# How to train a LSTM Neural Network to forecast a full "cycle" of a Time Series?

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, lstm, forecasting, recurrent-neural-network

I have the below data whose "cycles" grow in period over time:
[image]

My goal is to feed some fraction of this into a LSTM network in order to predict or forecast the remaining points (at least enough to make up one full cycle).

I've been trying to follow this tutorial: https://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-step-time-series-forecasting-long-short-term-memory-networks-python/ but it seems to train with small "windows" where we convert a 1D series of points into a training dataset X & Y, where the `X` column is made up of the first `n_lag` points and the corresponding y column represents the next `n_seq` points.

The predictions are then made in these small patches of points (below we zoom in and see these 5 predicted points stemming from each point of the test set).

[image]

Is there instead a way to feed in all the training data and then predict say ~50 points instead of 5 to capture the last full cycle or so? If this is possible, how does one go about forming the training data? It doesn't seem to work if I make `n_lag` = ~200 and `n_seq` = ~50.

Would the test set size then be equal to the number of points in each `Y` (length `n_seq`)?

Any advise would be greatly appreciated.